# getting exception trying to use google geocoding api

Tags: c#, geocoding

I was trying to use google geocoding api to convert address to longitude and latitude.but I am getting this exception

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'maps.googleapis.com'
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not
>   be resolved: 'maps.googleapis.com'

in the following line

```
 Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode("1600 pennsylvania ave washington dc").ToArray();
```

i am not getting what it is please somebody help me.

Comment: Well did you look at the stacktrace on the exception?

Comment: Check your event logs. The problem can be from an invalid url (hostname) to your firewall or proxy server blocking the request or even a misconfigured host file or DNS. As per Vigneshes answer, sometimes if you specifiy the proxy in the web.config your issue can go away.

Answer (score 1):

This thing is happen due to proxy setting in your system.Please add this code in your web.config file and it will work.

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for C#. If you are not calling Yahoo and Bing, why not just make the direct call to Google GeoService and make your project more lean.

```
    string uri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=123+Some+Adress,My+City,ST,12345&key=googleKey";

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri );
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Accept = "application/json";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var xdoc = response.GetResponseStream();
    String resposne = new StreamReader(xdoc).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score -1):

I also faced same issue. If you are connected with local area network and protected by Proxy server then Go in google chrome settings. Our system takes default settings from google chrome. In settings of chrome, go in proxy settings.Click on Lan setting.Click on proxy setting checkbox and click as well on by pass proxy server for local addresses.Also fill details of your proxy server in textbox. Go in advance and in exceptions field type localhost.Run project again.It will work.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer (neither as direct copies nor as links) to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.

Comment: But this is my own answer.I got solution this way.There are many questions which has same answer then what can we do....